# how to place horizontal scroll bar in Ext js Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, extjs

how to place horizontal scroll bar in Ext js Grid.

pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set autoScroll config property to true. As long as grid is wider than container it's in, a scroll bar should be rendered.